# Can I improve HD video playback for an NVIDIA card?

Tags: nvidia, video, vga

I'm using a NVIDIA card with the proprietary drivers, it can play HD videos but lags. Is there a way to buffer frames or something?

FX 5500, 173.xx (legacy, the new version does not support this card)

[image]

Seeking smooth HD playback on GStreamer-based players.

Comment: which variant of the FX5500 in terms of memory, clock speed do you have. The older and less capable variants couldnt cope with standard HD under windows - never mind trying this in ubuntu.  What resolution HD are you referring to in your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NVIDIA regarded the FX5500 as an entry level GPU and was capable of playing basic HD video under windows ([DirectX 9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_FX_Series)).  Direct support under Ubuntu is no longer available from NVIDIA - only through their legacy 173 driver.

You will struggle to play HD videos under Ubuntu - the fundamental issue is the lack of [VDPAU support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDPAU) for your graphics card in the NVIDIA driver.  VDPAU support is the ability for Ubuntu to offload graphics processing to the graphics card itself - without it your PC is doing much of this work.  It would be useful to add the specs of your PC into your question.

### Tips

1. Check if you have vsync support (Sync to VBlank) in your nvidia-settings (opengl/xvideo)-   Turning this on can help.
2. If you are feeling brave - look at [overclocking](http://www.linuxhardware.org/nvclock/#support) your FX5500 to maximise the framerate possible - search for "nvclock" in Software Center.  I've managed to overclock my Geforce 6 by an extra 10% which improves framerate slightly.
3. Compiz - this can slow down framerates - look at viewing your video under "Ubuntu Classic (No Effects)" if you are using Natty.  If lucid of maverick - look at using Compiz Fusion to do something similar.  Compiz, whilst not significant, if you are looking for the extra 2-5% performance boost could perhaps make a just that little bit of a difference to a slight lag issue.
4. You may have more luck with updated X-system.  Have a backup first just in-case you get blackscreens on boot - and the look to test with the [X-Swat PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates).
5. CPU overclock - I have a bios that allows my Athlon XP based CPU increase from 1.1GHz to 1.9Ghz - obviously this makes a significant difference in overall system performance - and does improve graphics decoding and encoding abilities.

Comment: Done points one and four. 720 plays smoothly, 1080 lags every so often. Point two I wouldn't dare - the internals gets centimeter thick layer of dust within weeks. But will point three have significant effect?

Comment: @Oxwivi - no - not a significant effect.  see my answer + tip 2 & 5.

Comment: Pentium IV 2.4 GHz here, I did not see any BIOS option to overlock so far.

Comment: shame - amd's are better overclockers than intel...

Comment: I see, well, your tips are all about I can do, I believe - thanks. I checked playback using Sintel trailers, just FYI.

Answer (score 0):

[some good tips here for optimising performance of HD playback with lower end nvidia gpus under 11.xx](http://confoundedtech.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/ubuntu-playing-1080i-hd-content-with.html)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.